# How can I set certain variables depending on the permissions of an opened file?

Tags: vim, buffer

I use Vim to open a bibtex file, but I export another bib-file and replace the original one often.

I'd like to reload the Vim buffer automatically to view the new bibtex file.

As far as I know, `:view file-name` will open a file with read-only mode.
And `set autoload` makes it load automatically.

How can I `set autoload` only when a file is opened with read-only permission?
Do I need to use certain `au Buffer..` variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a custom `:ViewAutoRead` command:

```
:command! -nargs=1 -complete=file ViewAutoRead view <args> | setlocal autoread
```

You can also combine the setting with the command:

```
:view +setl\ autoread filename
```

An `:autocmd` would be a general solution for *any* readonly file:

```
:autocmd BufRead * if &readonly | setlocal autoread | endif
```